# How to set null value for input list of values when returned from return values?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to JDeveloper and ADF and am developing in JDeveloper 12.2.1. I have two input LOV's. One LOV is a job code and the other LOV is an activity code. The way I have these set up is I have a search VO that has the job and activity code LOV's. Each LOV has it's own LOV VO as the data source. In each data source I return both the job and activity codes via a select statement. In the job code LOV VO, I have one view criteria item for the job code. In the activity code LOV VO, I have the view criteria set as the activity code. In the job code LOV, I want to set the value for the activity code, but the activity code could be null.

The issue I am having is that when I load the search form and enter in a job code that has no activity code, the search takes forever and neither job or activity code LOV's get set. Interesting thing is that when I set the job code LOV to a value that DOES have an activity code, the search is fast and sets both the job and activity code LOV values properly.

Is there a way to get this to work out of the box or do I have to do something custom?

If I have to do something custom, what examples are there to do this?

Comment: Can you check the sql query executed in backend for search when activity code is not present? May be your sql itself is taking time?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `adf` is throwing a null pointer excepcion: `NullPointerException`,
You feel that it never returns the corresponding row from the `database`, when actually the search for the register is halted due to the above caught exception.

One workaround is to add bound variables to the `job` and `activity` codes in the criteria of the *view object*, that way you would control the outcome of the `criteria` result.

Comment: By criteria in the view object do you mean create bind variables to be used with the view criteria or bind variables to be used in the where clause? I have tried adding bind variables and adding them to view criteria and it doesn't seem to be affecting the LOV at all. I even tried making the VO from an entity so that I could check the ignore nulls checkbox when setting up the view criteria.